# Imported products don't show on frontend

Tags: import

I'm trying to merge two installations. I recreated the websites and stores, plus categories and attributes from installation A in B. In a test environement I changed the apache vhost, and the sites work. I imported the products, and checked product settings like category, websites to see if they were imported correctly. Categories and websites are set to active, like the products. I emptied cache and reindexed. Product stocks are the same as in the original database.

The homepage stays empty. Going to a product details page on the (still working) production site, I copied the url and opened this page in the test environment: page not found. This is the same for all imported sites. The original sites and products in this installation work correctly.

I'm probably missing something basic, but I can't figure out what. Any ideas what it could be?

---

Update

It turned out to be a problem with the templates. For three templates, files were missing in `app/code/local` that were essential for the templates to work properly, and that were obviously not copied when copying the templates.

Comment: Are the products in stock?

Comment: Yes they are. I've restored a dump of the production database. Most products are in stock, and I would expect to see the same products on the homepage as on production. Besides that, if I open a details page directly, it should say "out of stock" instead of "page not found".

Comment: I should correct that. The imported products have stock values corresponding to their original values, which means most are in stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following product fields:

- **Visibility** - Is the product visible?
- **Tax Class** - Has a proper tax class been assigned?
- **Status** - Is this set to "enabled"?
- **Categories** - Is the product within the root category?

Maybe something didn't get copied over properly.

Comment: Visibility: Catalog, search; Tax class: Taxable goods; Status: Activate module (?); Categories: several products are in the root category for a specific website. "Activate module" seems a strange name, but it's the same for products that work (not imported - already in the database with different websites).

Comment: Just found out that for one website the products show up, so I'm going to try to find out why that works and the other sites not.

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with the templates. Some files in the app folder weren't copied. After comparing them I could fix all templates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've got exact duplicates of the database, then the problem must lie elsewhere (which means it's nothing to do with visibility, status, etc). I know you said you'd cleared the cache, but just to be safe, delete the contents of `/var/cache` and `/var/session`. 
Also, make sure that your .htaccess file copied over and that you have mod_rewrite and whatnot. It sounds stupid but I often tar up a site and move it over and I often end up loosing the .htaccess, which results in 404 errors all over the place.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problems and make sure .htaccess is copied. The test install (and installation process) works and I've used it for several month now. I use an exact copy of the database for the destination database, and that works with websites and products etc. I'm trying to merge the two installs, so the other db will not be identical - it will not be there! The imported products are not exact. I have to change categorie ids, some attribute names, replace some other values, because otherwise the import fails for those records. Clearing cache and session via terminal didn't help.

Comment: Deleting `var/session` is never an appropiate solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session