# Magento 1.9.2.3. not login in google chrome

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-7405, ce-1.9.2.3

Magento 1.9.2.3 login problem in admin pannel in google chrome
Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page
how to slove this problem

Comment: Are you using a custom admin theme ?

Comment: @Ishwar Are you still facing this issue? Have you tried what Digital Pianism mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem earlier:

- Clear your browser cookies
- Delete the content of var/session folder

That fixes the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem after switching to CGI. Delete the browser cache and cookies and it was working.

Comment: Deleting `var/session` is never an appropiate solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session

Answer (score 1):

try using 127.0.0.1 when you set up magento in localhost. I have also encounter same problem, that's the solution a have made and it works fine.

Comment: and also do that in local.xml, for better compatibility with console tools like n98. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to the recent Security Patch SUPEE-7405.

In most cases, the following will resolve the issue:

- Clear your browser cookies
- Delete the content of `var/session` folder

If the issue persists, check if you have a local version of `Mage_Core_Model_Session` in this path `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php`

If you do, you will need to update/migrate your local version to align with the new version of this file (`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php`)

If the issue persists, check whether anything in your project (e.g. your local code and any extensions you may use) overloads / extends the `Mage_Core_Model_Session` class.  If so, check if those extensions have any compatibility related updates you need to apply, and if not you may need to check yourself whether they introduce any breaking changes with the new `Mage_Core_Model_Session` class.

Comment: Deleting `var/session` is never an appropiate solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue of the last patch SUPEE-7405 included in Magento 1.9.2.3 release.
Please see this post to check issues : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98236/33619

Answer (score 0):

Also you might want to

- check your cookie-domain settings (base_url = local.whatever.com -> cookie_domain .local.whatever.com or .whatever.com)
- make sure you have ssl installed if you use 'use secure url in backend'-setting. if you have a non-https-domain entered in secure_url, do not enable 'use secure url in backend/frontend'-setting, it keeps cookies from http-access