# Merged JS and CSS do not work when Production mode

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

I was in **developer mode**, everything was great, when I **changed to Production mode**, the Merged options of CSS and JS seem to be ignored, it was back listing all css and js.

Also the product page only shows the pictures of the product in developer mode, after changing to production mode they disappear.

Any thought to help me?

---

The point is, I'm doing it.

Here is what I did in sequence:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento indexer:reindex

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

bin/magento setup:di:compile

bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And before even starting, the Merge options are YES and I was in developer mode.

Comment: Hello, Have you got any solution of this issue, I am getting same issue in magento 2.0.7. Please give the solution if you have any, Thanks

Comment: same issue i am facing it please help me

Answer (score 22):

I just did the following and the problem was solved:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento indexer:reindex

bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s

# Here was the secret: run the di:compile after production
bin/magento setup:di:compile  

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: i tried same way but no luck

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: If i execute command "production -s" it blank my site and give very unusal error:  Warning: include(/siteRoot/html/var/view_preprocessed/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /siteRoot/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php on line 312

Comment: Another - that worked for me. In case anyone else is having the problem I was. CSS would minify and bundle, but JS would not, despite having the options enabled in the admin. Adding the -s in the set product mode made all the difference. Also, the backend is MUCH faster now as well. I was using the same order and commands, but it was the "-s" that made the difference, Thank you

Comment: Do i first need to switch back to development mode? I did what you mentioned, but no difference....

Comment: I had the same issue. It would not load images in production mode and I couldnt get my backend to work. The wheel would just spin. When I did it on a development subdomain it worked fine, but on the production domain where SSL is enabled, I get the spinning wheel for images (on product page) and backend.

Comment: Worked for me GREAT

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you check your NGINX configuration file as well.

If there is a variable `$MAGE_MODE` set there it needs to be changed to `production` as well, and save the file

After that you will need to reload or restart NGINX depending on your preference.

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

OR

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

After that check your `app/etc/env.php` and see if the `MAGE_MODE` array key is set to `production` as well if not change it to `production` or you can use the command

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

After you executed the command check if the value changed `app/etc/env.php`, sometimes there might be permission issues.

Next, clean out the `pub/static` folder.

```
rm -rf pub/static/*
```

Clear/Flush your cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now you are ready to execute the static content deploy

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar issue. The cause for no image is because there is an error in JS file after **minify** JS. You can verify it in your browser (firebug etc).

> .../div>';return __p};})(window,document,location,typeof
>   jQuery!=='undefined'&&jQu

I solved this by remove all the file in **var/cache/** and **pub/static/** and setup:static-content:deploy again

But there is still another issue, it's about the braintree if you enable it. Braintree doesn't show up due to another JS error.

> Error: Script error for:
>   https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>
> ...Error(id,msg,err,requireModules){var e=new
>   Error(msg+'\nhttp://requirejs.org/doc...

For now, I simply don't use the minify js function to avoid the trouble until solution is found.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps that worked for me on Magento ver. 2.1.7 with Redis (not running Varnish). However, it's still unclear if everything is working as it should. JS is minified and bundled (unclear what merge is supposed to do). CSS is minified (not seeing it merged).

1. Turn off all Magento cache.
2. Clear redis cache.
3. Turn all five css/js configs on (either in admin or via database).
4. Generate static files.
5. Clear Magento cache (command line). For safety (may not be required).
6. Clear opcache (if not set to auto refresh).
7. Refresh frontend home page (and check browser console for errors).
8. Turn on Magento cache.

dev/css/merge_css_files = 1
dev/css/minify_files = 1
dev/js/enable_js_bundling = 1
dev/js/merge_files = 1
dev/js/minify_files = 1

Simply turning on the configs and clearing cache didn't work -- the frontend browser console reported a lot of js errors.

Comment: Merge will merge your files together into one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to flush the JavaScript/CSS? You can do this under System>Cache Management and then press the button which is on the bottom of the table on the left 'Flus JavaScript/CSS Cache'

Comment: YEP.... flush js, then cache. Nothing change. However, if I switch to Developer mode, the merge works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redeploy static after enabling this option in production mode.

Comment: The point is, I'm doing it. I just posted here what I did.

Comment: If it not works then problem maybe in in permission. Can you check your webserver access/errors log

Answer (score 0):

I just did the following and the problem was solved.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento indexer:reindex

bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s

bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

(Here was the secret, to run the di:compile after production)

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the problem when the JavaScript is un-compiled the jquery selector works.

```
$('#my_element').click(function(){ alert('Hello World');});
```

But once compiled, compressed and joined, I then need to code:-

```
$('body #my_element').click(function(){ alert('Hello World');});
```

Don't ask why, it seems that when reading directly from the cache, the requirejs code executes before the domReady and the elements attach to different elements in some different page.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your pub/static folder. Maybe the www-data group doesn't have a write permision to create _cache folder. I've deleted static folder manually in command line. Therefore it can not create _cache folder.

Take a look at var/log/exceptions.log: `tail -f var/log/exception.log`
In my case:

```
[2020-09-26 12:28:24] main.CRITICAL: Le répertoire "/data/var/www/preprod/www/pub/static/_cache" ne peut être crée Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Le répertoire \"/data/var/www/vgc-preprod/www/pub/static/_cache\" ne peut être crée Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied at /data/var/www/preprod/www/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:227)"}
```

So:

`chmod 777 -r pub/static`

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

If already check in database that css and js merge enabled and also checked all deployment commands but after deployment it getting rolled back and sowing not merge on browser.

Same happened with because i used custom deployment pipeline with nginx server. so, i checked and set the files and directory to write permissions for system owner as user.

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
sudo find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

It worked well to me.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score -1):

Delete cache manually var/cache and delete session manually var/session

Comment: Deleting `var/session` is never an appropiate solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session

Answer (score -1):

1. Please also enable "Enable JavaScript Bundling" option

   store->configuration->advanced->developer->javascript setting->
2. Enable JavaScript Bundling set to "yes" And flush cache

Comment: Haphazard advice that has nothing to do with the question.