# Permission change after setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, permissions, file-permissions

For some reason every time I compile or setup:upgrade the file permissions on my server change and my site's layout is affected. Does anyone know what can be causing this?

Comment: Are you clearing your cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my answer to [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/223459/60221).

The problem here is that newly generated files are owned by the user and group who issues the command `$USER:$USER`, where they should belong to `$USER:www-data` or `$USER:apache`. Because apache2 does not have access to the group `$USER`, the website cannot be properly served.

In order to retain proper permissions, magento commands should be executed as the apache user.

For example:

#### Ubuntu

`$ sudo -u www-data php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

#### CentOS

`$ sudo -u apache php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

This way, new files are owned by `www-data:www-data` (in the case of ubuntu).

So long as you have properly followed Magento's documentation with regards to permissions and added the cli user to the apache2 group, then you will have proper access to the files.

If you did not follow this documentation then you can execute the following command to do so:

#### Ubuntu

`$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER`

#### CentOS

`$ sudo usermod -a -G apache $USER`

#### Note:

In order that commands can be executed without declaring the apache2 user, [Daniel's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93892/60221) explains that we can modify how the Magento framework sets permissions for new files.

Answer (score 1):

I am using linux and apache and only these steps worked for me.

```
sudo chown -R <username>:www-data /var/www/html/<project name>

systemctl restart apache2 (restarting apache)

sudo adduser <username> www-data (add system user to apache server group)

cd /var/www/html/<project name>

chmod -R g+s pub/static pub/media generated (folders which inherit the parent permissions)
```