# JS and CSS merged Issue in magento2

Tags: magento2, js-css

I tried below step to merge and minify js and css

> bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant
>
> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

when I open the website in browser along with merged file I can see all other js file also loading

[image]

please help me out

in admin side

> Enable Javascript Bundling :- Yes
>
> Merge JavaScript Files :- Yes.
>
> Minify JavaScript Files :- Yes

Comment: The way RequireJS works in Magento 2 is it (usually) loads the scripts only when required, so a certain script won't load until a certain element has loaded in the DOM. By doing this I'm not sure how merging JS would work, for example if you were to merge all JS files and then load an element in the DOM that required a script how could that be merged into the rest of the merged JS? Because of this I'm not sure how possible it is to merge all JS loaded via RequireJS.

Comment: Hi @Pradeep Kumar did you get any solution? Facing same issue in Magento 2.1.2 CE Version

Comment: @AnkitShah :- check my latest answer

Comment: @BenCrook I have not yet understood so well how "Enable javascript Boundling" works, I have many doubt about that. But I think that with this config active the server itself create the bundles, not requireJS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cleared the static files. I'm not quite sure if setup static:deploy does that (I never use it for changes like this)

And also, perhaps developer mode would help?
php bin/magento  deploy:mode:set developer

I'd try deleting the static & var folders
Remove pub/static
Remove var/cache
Remove var/composer_home
Remove var/generation
Remove var/page_cache
Remove var/view_preprocessed

Comment: in developer mode you cannot merge the js and css files

Comment: That doesn't appear to be true Mr Kumar

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106436/merged-js-and-css-do-not-work-when-production-mode

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue. The cause for no image is because there is an error in JS file after **minify** JS. You can verify it in your browser (firebug etc).

> .../div>';return __p};})(window,document,location,typeof
>   jQuery!=='undefined'&&jQu

I solved this by remove all the file in **var/cache/** and **pub/static/** and setup:static-content:deploy again

But there is still another issue, it's about the braintree if you enable it. Braintree doesn't show up due to another JS error.

> Error: Script error for:
>   https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>
> ...Error(id,msg,err,requireModules){var e=new
>   Error(msg+'\nhttp://requirejs.org/doc...

For now, I simply don't use the minify js function to avoid the trouble until solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps i followed for merged and minify and it works for me

1. in admin 
     Enable Javascript Bundling :- Yes
     Merge JavaScript Files :- Yes.
     Minify JavaScript Files :- Yes
    and also CSS
2. set production mode You have to set production mode in htacces or ngnix        configuration 
   that is 
   SetEnv MAGE_MODE production  (.htaccess)

   set $MAGE_MODE production;  (ngnix cong file)
3. clear cache and run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   if you have multi locale than run enlish last that is

   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ar_KW en_US

Answer (score 0):

Please check your pub/static folder. Maybe the www-data group doesn't have a write permision to create _cache folder. I've deleted static folder manually in command line. Therefore it can not create _cache folder.

Take a look at var/log/exceptions.log: `tail -f var/log/exception.log`
In my case:

```
[2020-09-26 12:28:24] main.CRITICAL: Le répertoire "/data/var/www/preprod/www/pub/static/_cache" ne peut être crée Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Le répertoire \"/data/var/www/vgc-preprod/www/pub/static/_cache\" ne peut être crée Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied at /data/var/www/preprod/www/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:227)"}
```

So:

`chmod 777 -r pub/static`

Hope it can help.