# Magento2.1 CSS/JS minify and merge

Tags: magento-2.1, js-css, merge-css, minify

I just put merge and minify html css and js to yes in admin panel of magento2.1. I'm in production mode and clean and flush cache and indexer are reindex but still I see all css and js files in page source that are not merged and minified. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Command And Check :-**

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento indexer:reindex

bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s

#Here was the secret: run the di:compile after production
bin/magento setup:di:compile  

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

[Merged JS and CSS do not work when Production mode
Ask](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106436/merged-js-and-css-do-not-work-when-production-mode)

Comment: Did it, nothing happens