# Any link redirect to one same product, only /checkout/cart don't - Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

I was using the site normally and suddenly it ***started to redirect all categories and products to one same item***, if I **copy and paste** the URI for products that are **active it shows 404**.

**Any idea how I can debug it?**

I already clear cache, reindexed and compiled again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean up following folders

- var/view_preprocessed
- var/page_cache
- var/generation
- var/cache

Go to `pub/static` and clean up

> find . -depth -name .htaccess -prune -o -delete

then run static deploy. Try [Full Cache Clean](http://www.forgeonline.co.nz/magento-2-development-cache-clean-up-process/) up

Comment: Deleting `var/session` is never an appropiate solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session

Comment: Yes that is true. I've removed it from this question